# $_POST spaces converted in underscores

Tags: php, post

I have an HTML dropdown menu that looks like this

```
<select name='not working random test!'>
<option value='0'>Select quantity:</option>
<option value='1'>1 room</option>
<option value='2'>2 rooms</option>
</select>
```

Is it even possible that, if I'm var_dumping $_POST, I see something like this?

```
["not_working_random_test!"]=>
string(1) "1"
```

This is causing some troubles with my engine: I expect the name I specify for the select to be the same. Why is this not happening?

Comment: *Why is this not happening?* — Because PHP is magic (this might be a contributing factor to my not using it). (I assume that this is a legacy of the original behaviour, which was to populate global variables instead of a superglobal array. You can't have spaces in variable names).

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? More detail and code would be nice

Comment: What you are showing is perfectly normal behaviour? whats the problem?

Comment: If you insist on using such name and get unwanted result, you can use the classic $_POST[0] if your select field is the first form field

Comment: Besides being normal behavior for php, using spaces in array keys is ridiculously bad practice.

Comment: I see no reason whatsoever to object to spaces in array keys; except when it comes to POST

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is standard PHP behaviour.  From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.external.php):

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.

---

The full list of field-name characters that PHP converts to `_` (underscore) is the following (not just dot):

- chr(32)   (space)
- chr(46) `.` (dot)
- chr(91) `[` (open square bracket)
- chr(128) - chr(159) (various)

If *both* an open and a closing square bracket are present, they are not converted but the $_POST element becomes an array element.

```
<input name='hor[se'>
<input name='hor[se]'>
```

will become:

```
$_POST['hor_se'];
$_POST['hor']['se'];
```

::[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#81080)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Didn't even suspected this could be possible. And how then can I understand if an underscore was a dot or a space?

Comment: @Saturnix By not using spaces or dots in input names. By not relying on names to store data at all.

Comment: Even after 1 year of dealing in PHP, I didn't knew this +1 for teaching me a new thing.

Comment: I'll bet it's a legacy from when people used `import_request_variables()`, since dot and spaces aren't allowed in variable names. Although it would make more sense just to do the conversion in the variable names, not the `$_POST` keys.

Comment: Thanks. I've just spent two hours trying to debug an Ajax script, trying to figure out why a `FormData()` object wasn't arriving on the server. It turns out **it was**, but PHP was updating the key names immediately after arrival.

Comment: Thanks everyone. But now I want to use `$name=encode($thing)` on my `<input name="\"$name\"">` and `$thing=decode(array_keys($_POST)[0])` on the answer. So what `encode` / `decode` is the Right Thing here?

Comment: Edit: `urlencode` and `urldecode` seem the right tools for the job.