# Why getting the following doesnt work in php?

Tags: php

Assuming I have the url:

```
http://localhost/mypage.php?my.var.is=Value

echo $_GET['my.var.is_this'];
```

The echo statement above does not appear to print out "Value". How do I properly access this parameter?

Comment: var_dump($_GET) to see exactly it is being interpreted.

Comment: The question is; why do you have urls like that in the first place? Change them to something sensible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\_POST spaces converted in underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092398/post-spaces-converted-in-underscores)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.
>
> – http://php.net/variables.external

Comment: So what if you have `http://localhost/mypage.php?my.var.is=Value1&my_var_is=Value2`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly the latter should overwrite the first?

Comment: @cheesemacfly why not try it and see? (SPOILER: the same happens as `?my_var=ant&my_var=bat&my_var=cat`)

Comment: Faire enough. Just though it would be good to add it to your answer since it is not precised in the doc. (I just tested and @bwoebi got it right!)