# html form transforming name upon submit

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have a form that is basically a bunch of questions from a survey where you answer with radio buttons. These questions are pulled from an Excel spreadsheet and as such the ID of each question depends on what a human puts in the ID field for that question.

In this situation, the name of each radio group is the ID of the question itself.

Recently I had to insert a new question Excel sheet where the IDs contained a '.' so like 'Q.1'. In this situation, the name of the radio group was fine on the HTML page 'Q.1' but once I posted the form, and would retrieve the name in my php using the array_keys function, I would get 'Q_1'.

I copied the w3schools post and tried it out with this being in my frontend :

```html
<form action="/my/php/method/test" method="post">
  <label for="FSM-1.0">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="FSM-1.0" value="John"><br>
  <label for="FSM-1.2.3">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="FSM-1.2.3" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And then in my php method that receives this form I simply put :

```
public function test() {
   var_dump($_POST);
}
```

And the result always gives me:

/var/www/html/app/controllers/Admin.php:25:

**array** *(size=2)*

'FSM-1_0' => string 'John' *(length=4)*

'FSM-1_2_3' => string 'Doe' *(length=3)*

Is this normal? I need the array_keys to be exact, and as such do I need to replace the '.' in my Excel file?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092398/post-spaces-converted-in-underscores

Comment: Ah I see it's the same for spaces. Thank you! Guess I will add another restraint on the Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal. PHP will do this (and it's a little annoying). You can't really change this.