# Sending array having space in keys being removed when sending by cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have a strange issue.

```
$arr = array(
  'my key 1' => 'Some data 1',
  'my_key_2' => 'Some data 2',
  'my key 3' => 'Some data 3',
);
```

I am sending this data using cURL ...

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

On receiveing end, I am just printing it back.

`echo print_r($_POST);`

Which prints it out as

```
array(
  [0] => 0,
  [my_key_2] => Some data 2,
)
```

It's removing array keys with spacing.

Any ideas, what could be causing it?

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: hi - I am stuck at the above point as my data becomes 'corrupt' at receiving end as keys with space in the array gets deleted.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092398/post-spaces-converted-in-underscores) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spaces in params are replaced with `+` when you use `http_build_query()`,
try providing an array without this function when you set the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option.

You can read about it in docs...
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php#95784

Comment: Thank you. Yes that's the exact issue I am having. Let me try without http_build_query().